# HttpClient got error with EstablishSslConnectionAsync at SendAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have *ApiAdapter* with using HttpClient to send HTTP requests to my server.
to avoid create to many HttpClient, I am using DependenceInjection with singleton mode for "ApiAdapter" class. it works well when I call only one by one HTTP request

I want to use Parallel.ForEachAsync to reduce performance time because I want to create 1000 people through ApiAdapter.
It throw exception with below message error after it created ~ 30 - 100 person
with message:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
at System.Collections.CollectionBase.OnValidate(Object value)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection.OnValidate(Object value)
at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection.AddRange(X509CertificateCollection value)
at System.Net.Security.CertificateHelper.GetEligibleClientCertificate(X509CertificateCollection candidateCerts)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.<set_ClientCertificateOptions>b__57_0(Object sender, String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, String[] acceptableIssuers)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.UserCertSelectionCallbackWrapper(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate remoteCertificate, String[] acceptableIssuers)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer, Byte[]& output) at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(ReadOnlySpan`1 incomingBuffer)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, Cancellatio
nToken originalCancellationToken)
at ---------.ApiAdapter.PostRequestAsync

```
Here is my code 
public async Task RequestPerson()
{
    var threadRequestPins = Enumerable.Range(0, listSize).ToList();
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(datasToProcess, async (_, token) =>{
        var fakfurTestApiService = LoadTestKernel.Kernel.Get<IFakfurApiService>();
        var personCreated = await fakfurTestApiService.CallPostRequestAsync(<Url path>, <dataBody>);
        //CallPostRequestAsync will call ApiAdapter with PostRequestAsync() method below
    });
}

//constructor
public ApiAdapter()
{
    _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = _cookieContainer
    };
    _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler);
}

private void AddCertificates()
{
    if (_certificate2Collection != null )
    {
        _httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(_certificate2Collection);
    }
}

public async Task<TResult> PostRequestAsync<TResult, TBodyRequest>(string testApiRelativeUrl, TBodyRequest bodyRequest,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where TResult : class
{
    var uriBuilder = BuildRequestUri(testApiRelativeUrl);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uriBuilder.Uri);
    AddCertificate(request);
    request.Content = new StringContent(_jsonSerializer.SerializeObject(bodyRequest), Encoding.UTF8,;
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    return await ExtractBodyFromResponseAsync<TResult>(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to guage what's actually going on here as the code you have provided is missing alot.

However, as per this issue > https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52779
You cannot add certificates whilst building the request or when the HttpClient is in use.

You should use the `SocketsHttpHandler` class instead of `HttpClientHandler`.

You can assign your certificate handler delegate in your constructor.

```
    private readonly CookieContainer _cookieContainer;
    private readonly SocketsHttpHandler _socketsHttpHandler;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    //constructor
    public ApiAdapter()
    {
        _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        _socketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = _cookieContainer,
            SslOptions = new System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                LocalCertificateSelectionCallback = (object sender, string targetHost, X509CertificateCollection localCertificates, X509Certificate? remoteCertificate, string[] acceptableIssuers) =>
                {
                    return <your certificate here>;

                }
            }
        };
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_socketsHttpHandler);
    }
```

Sidenote: If you're using .NET Core you should really look into using [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) to reference your services such as the HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ripmax, using SocketsHttpHandler fix my issue with your sample code above.